# Silverlight ComboBox SelectedValue TwoWay Binding not working

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight-4.0

I have used many ComboBoxes in my applications and all of them are working without any problem. But, I can't find the problem now. I have set SelectedValuePath to "Tag" property. But the property not updating after changing the ComboBox selected item. I have read other StackOverflow questions, but nontheless helped.

It is xaml:

> xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication1"

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vms:MainViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <ComboBox Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe UI"
         Height="30" Margin="0,5,0,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedDifStatusComparer, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
         SelectedValuePath="Tag">
        <ComboBox.Items>
            <ComboBoxItem Tag="H" >High</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Tag="L" >Low</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Tag="E" >Equal</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox.Items>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

And here is the ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        private string _selectedDifStatusComparer = "";
        private string SelectedDifStatusComparer
        {
            get { return _selectedDifStatusComparer; }
            set
            {
                _selectedDifStatusComparer = value;
                MessageBox.Show(_selectedDifStatusComparer);
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedDifStatusComparer");
            }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            SelectedDifStatusComparer = "E"; // It is working, the MessageBox is apperaing
        }
    }
```

Comment: pls check your output window for binding errors or use Snoop at runtime to check your binding

Comment: @blindmeis It worked, I just forgot to make property public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property is private. Change it to public and it should work.

Comment: Thanks. I can't beleieve that. :)  It seems that, I am tired.

Answer (score 2):

Your property is private. Change it to public and it should work.

```
 public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }

            private string _selectedDifStatusComparer = "";
            public string SelectedDifStatusComparer
            {
                get { return _selectedDifStatusComparer; }
                set
                {
                    _selectedDifStatusComparer = value;
                    MessageBox.Show(_selectedDifStatusComparer);
                    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedDifStatusComparer");
                }
            }

            public MainViewModel()
            {
                SelectedDifStatusComparer = "E"; // It is working, the MessageBox is apperaing
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have already accepted another answer 6 days ago :)