# Silver Light ComboBox Selected Value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight

I have a combo box in silverlight application, I have a checkbox and a textbox in it, I have to set selected Value of ComboBox,but its not getting selected, 
I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873605/silverlight-combobox-selectedvalue-twoway-binding-not-working) link, but its not working 
This is my ComboBox

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Types" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedType, Mode=TwoWay}"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="2,8,-2,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="28" Padding="3">                        
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="All">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="105" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <CheckBox  Name="all" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="All" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Style="{x:Null}" FontSize="11"/>                            
        </Grid>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="General">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="105" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <CheckBox Name="General" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" />
            <TextBlock Text="General" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Style="{x:Null}" FontSize="11"/>
            <TextBox Text="180" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="11" Padding="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"/>
        </Grid>
    </ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

This is my SelectedProperty

```
private string _selectdType = "";
public string SelectedType
{
    get { return _selectdType; }
    set
    {
        _selectdType = value;
        MessageBox.Show(_selectdType);
        NotifyOfPropertyChange("SelectedType");
    }
}
```

and in My ViewModel constructor, I am setting it like this

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    SelectedType="All";
}
```

But ComboBox is appearing without any selected value(ie blank).
I also tried with Name property instead of Tag but no luck

Comment: Have you tried to debug the binding with a Converter..?

Comment: No, I am new in silver light, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `SelectedValuePath` property for `SelectedValue` to be able to work properly :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Types" 
          SelectedValuePath="Tag"
          ......
          >
    ......
</ComboBox>
```